# How to combine two regex conditions?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write a regular expression in JavaScript that ANDs two conditions A and B

`(A)(B)` is obviously not a valid solution.

My two regex are:

`^((?=.*?(.*([\.]).*)[^@])[^@]+)$`

`^((?!\.\.).)*$`

so
`^((?=.*?(.*([\.]).*)[^@])[^@]+)(((?!\.\.).)*)$` does not AND the two regexes

How can I do that ? is there a general rule ?

Comment: You already seem to know lookaheads, so... `(?=A)(?:B)`

Comment: `^(?=.*?(.*([\.]).*)[^@])(?!\.\.)[^@]+$`

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, there isn't an obvious way to combine to expressions. Like you said, `(A)(B)` is not valid. Since regular expressions aren't a programming language, the "obvious" way to do what you're looking for is:

```
var doesMatch = string.match(/(A)/) && string.match(/(B)/);
```

Without taking the time to really decipher what you're trying to match, it's hard to say if there is a non-obvious way to combine the two expressions...all I can say is there isn't a generic rule to combine them.

Also, combining two regular expression doesn't necessarily mean it's faster. Take the string `foo bar` and the expressions `^foo` and `bar$`. The "obvious" combination of those two expressions is `^foo.*?bar$`; however, `^foo` and `bar$` each take 5 steps while the combined version takes 11 steps.

Comment: "Without taking the time to really decipher ..." Just think how much more time it would take to decipher *after* they are combined. For this reason I prefer the && approach. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them like as follows

```
^(?=.*?(.*([\.]).*)[^@])((?!\.\.)[^@])+$
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/eX5hF1/2)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks for the time spent on analysing the regexes, but this answer does not produce valid results as it matches `example..com`
Also was looking for a more generic answer

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking it down to the actual conditions you're testing for; I see three of them:

- contains at least one dot (`.`)
- doesn't contain a double dot (`..`)
- one or more of any characters except `@`

Convert two of them to lookaheads, then chain all three together into one regex. That would be:

```
^(?=.*\.)(?!.*\.\.)[^@]+$
```

But maybe you want to be sure it doesn't start or end with a dot.  That's easier to do *without* lookaheads:

```
^[^@.]+(?:\.[^@.]+)+$
```